# How to return JSON data after a 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax request I make to my REST API after a user enters incorrect form details, for example: An invalid username, blank email address, etc. The data returned looks like this:

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
{
    "username": [
        "Username already taken."
    ],
    "email": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ],
    "password1": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ],
    "password2": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ]
}
```

Here's my code:

```
console.log(send_data(register_url, data));

function send_data(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
        },

        error: function (xhr) {
        }
    });
}
```

When I call the function, I do retrieve all of the data. Like so:

```
abort: ƒ (e)
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ (e)
done: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (e)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (e)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (e)
readyState: 4
responseJSON: {email: Array(1), password1: Array(1), password2: Array(1)}
responseText: "{"email":["This field is required."],"password1":["This field is required."],"password2":["This field is required."]}"
setRequestHeader: ƒ (e,t)
state: ƒ ()
status: 400
statusCode: ƒ (e)
statusText: "Bad Request"
then: ƒ (t,r,i)
__proto__: Object
```

However, when I do this:

```
let resp = send_data(register_url, data);
console.log(resp.responseJSON);
```

I get `undefined` when in my JavaScript console. Why is that? Why can't I retrieve the data in responseJSON?

Comment: because it's async

Comment: @eugensunic but why do I retrieve the data in the beginning?

Comment: you don't you retrieve the object parameters of the ajax

Comment: @eugensunic What do you mean by object parameters? I retrieve the data in responseJSON and responseText. If it didn't work, I wouldnt be receiving this data correct?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

To show your data, only use callbacks specified in ajax, success or error, no other way. You can of-course use Promises or async task es 7 features but I see that you are relying on jquery lib.

```
function send_data(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
           console.log('received data', data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
         console.log('Error occured, proceed with some logic')
        }
    });
}
```

You are getting the wrong impression that you get some kind of result whereas you get the ajax object result since you are returning it. You are just getting all of its functions and properties since it's a complex object.

```
send_data(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({})
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I need to get that data outside of the send_data function though, is that possible? For example do something like `let resp = send_data(url, data);`

Comment: Can you store it in a outer variable inside the success and then use it accross

Comment: Like a global variable outside of Ajax, and then change the contents of that variable inside error? Btw, error is where I get the data from when the user enters invalid form data not success

Comment: Yes, but that's not good practice there are other ways in which you could preform the storage of the variable, but for more look online

Comment: I'm using Django rest-auth, so it's creating this

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` is async or not wait to finish to continue next operation, this why you get `undefined` for `console.log(resp.responseJSON);`

you need callback function

```
function send_data(url, data, callback) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: callback,
    error: callback
  });
}

function ajaxCallback(data, status, jqXHR) {
  //if (status == "success") {}
  //else {}
  resp = jqXHR;
  console.log(resp.responseJSON);
}

let resp;
send_data(register_url, data, ajaxCallback);
```